# How to make text-align right in selectbox list in Android chrome

Tags: android, html, css, right-to-left, mobile-chrome

I have a website which has Arabic version. While accessing the website from mobile, the menu will be shown as a select box list. Since the Arabic is rtl I need the text to be aligned to right. I have tried adding CSS to *select* attribute. but it is not working in Android chrome. How can I add css style for the menu shown in attached image.

[image: android screenshot]

Comment: @MurtazaHussain didn't worked :(

Comment: sorry @jubin it isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

As Murtaza Hussain said, you can the CSS,

```css
select > option {
    direction: rtl; /* This makes the text direction go from right to left */
    text-align: right;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<select dir="rtl">
  <option>
    واحد
    one
  </option>
  <option>
    اثنين
    two
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Chrome on Android. Once you tap on the `<select>` element, the text remains aligned to the left, instead of to the right.