# Android Chrome Browser. Incorrect selection popup rtl text direction

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, right-to-left

While using android selection field I found out one issue with RTL text in selection popup.
If text begins with English characters then text in selection popup will not apply rtl style.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U70Ot.png)
As you can see, first and third options were displayed without rtl style.
Look like, direction of the text in popup depends from characters in option tag.

On desktop browser selection field display all options correctly.

I tried other approachs, like:

- unicode-bidi: bidi-override; style
- dir attribute on selection or options

but all of them didn't help me with this issue.

Does chrome have some option to force rtl style for selection field in popup ?
Does this behavior normal for mobile browser ?

Chrome Version: 43.0.2490.76

Example code:

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select>
        <option value="0">A اختر</option>
        <option value="1">ذكر C</option>
        <option value="2">A أثنى</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Css

```
.dropdown {
    direction: rtl;
}

select{
    width:125px;
    float:left;
}
```

You can see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2p0pjxc/

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28146034/247696

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```css
.dropdown {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}

select{
    width:125px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <select>
        <option value="0">A اختر</option>
        <option value="1">C ذكر</option>
        <option value="2">A أثنى</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Android Chrome. Once I tap on the `<select>` control, the text is aligned left instead of being aligned right.

Comment: You can put the text in a <bdo> or <bdi> and give it a different text-align. I doubt there is a proper way to make both the English & Arabic text into one alignable text. You can though put one in a <bdo> for example.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to make it work even with just Arabic text. You're welcome to edit your answer if you think `<bdo>` or `<bdi>` would work.